# Java Thread Safety Issue in Struts ScopeInterceptor class?

Tags: java, struts2, thread-safety, hashmap

I'm trying to understand if there is a thread-safety issue inside of Struts2 ScopeInterceptor class (/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ScopeInterceptor.java), here's the code in question:

```
    private static Map locks = new IdentityHashMap();

static final void lock(Object o, ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    synchronized (o) {
        int count = 3;
        Object previous = null;
        while ((previous = locks.get(o)) != null) {
            if (previous == invocation) {
                return;
            }
            if (count-- <= 0) {
                locks.remove(o);
                o.notify();

                throw new StrutsException("Deadlock in session lock");
            }
            o.wait(10000);
        }
        ;
        locks.put(o, invocation);
    }
}

static final void unlock(Object o) {
    synchronized (o) {
        locks.remove(o);
        o.notify();
    }
}
```

I have a Websphere application showing 45 stalled threads, high cpu usage. 33 threads are stalled at "locks.remove(o)" inside of "unlock" method. The other 12 threads are stalled inside of "locks.get(o)" inside of "lock" method.

It seems to me that the usage of IdentityHashMap is thread-unsafe. Could simply wrapping IdentityHashMap with Collections.synchronizedMap() solve this problem?:

```
    private static Map locks = Collections.synchronizedMap(new IdentityHashMap());

static final void lock(Object o, ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    synchronized (o) {
        int count = 3;
        Object previous = null;
        while ((previous = locks.get(o)) != null) {
            if (previous == invocation) {
                return;
            }
            if (count-- <= 0) {
                locks.remove(o);
                o.notify();

                throw new StrutsException("Deadlock in session lock");
            }
            o.wait(10000);
        }
        ;
        locks.put(o, invocation);
    }
}

static final void unlock(Object o) {
    synchronized (o) {
        locks.remove(o);
        o.notify();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the author tried to "fix" IdentityHashMap's synchronization problem by using synchronized code blocks, however that doesn't protect against multiple threads if the Object "o" is a thread-specific object. And, since the code blocks within lock and unlock are separate, then IdentityHashMap will (and does!) get called simultaneously by more than one thread (as per our Java core evidence).

Is the Collections.synchronizedMap() wrapper the correct fix, or am I missing something?

Comment: FYI - I did tons of research on IdentityHashMap (and all Java HashMaps). It seems like almost all are *not* thread-safe; with the exception of ConcurrentHashMap. Unfortunately, ConcurrentHashMap doesn't support null objects, so simply replacing IdentityHashMap with ConcurrentHashMap won't work for this situation.

Comment: More info - the IdentityHashMap .get and .remove methods are typically very, very fast - about a micro-second per call on a typical single-threaded server. So, it seems very odd to me that we should have 45 threads that just "happen" to be stalled (and churning CPU) inside of these methods.

Comment: The best approach seems to be implement your own version of ScopeInterceptor and test :-)

Comment: Possibly related, Struts Interceptors are thread-unsafe: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878799/are-interceptors-in-struts2-thread-unsafe

Comment: After further research into the code, it may be possible (and certainly better performance) to use `private static Map locks = new ConcurrentHashMap();` on the first line instead of the `Collections.syncrhonizedMap()` wrapper.

Comment: We are going to try Lukasz's suggestion and will post results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are right, and there appears to be a thread safety issue. The developer is attempting to be thread safe by synchronizing on the object "o", but it looks like this object is actually the session object rather than something that is scoped more widely. I believe the change needs to be to synchronize on the locks object.

Answer (score 0):

No real answers, but hopefully some useful information:

The IdentityHashMap documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) states:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an identity hash map concurrently, and at least one of
>   the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated
>   with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural
>   modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some
>   object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists,
>   the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap
>   method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental
>   unsynchronized access to the map:
>
> Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new IdentityHashMap(...));

So the Collections.synchronizedMap strategy sounds right, but this page (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) makes me wonder about whether it will work since the methods are static:

> **Locks In Synchronized Methods**
>
> When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires
>   the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the
>   method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused
>   by an uncaught exception.
>
> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is
>   invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an
>   object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the
>   Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static
>   fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any
>   instance of the class.

Since those are static methods (even though the fields are not static), it's hard to tell if the Collections.synchronizedMap wrapper will really work to prevent a deadlock...  My answer is that I have no answer!

Comment: Thanks for the link about static methods and thread safety, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think so.
If you accessing  lock(Object o, ActionInvocation invocation) with different os you are modify the IdentityHashMap simultaneously with different monitors for the different threads. This makes it possible for different threads to call IdentityHashMap simultaneously.

This can be solved by synchronizing the IdentityHashMap.