# Is a Struts 2 Interceptor which puts and pops to Value Stack thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2, thread-safety, struts2-interceptors

Consider an interceptor which puts an object in Value Stack, do some logic and then removes it:

```
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("user", CurrentUser);

doSomeLogic();

ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().pop();
```

As mentioned in [Are Interceptors in Struts2 Thread UNsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878799/are-interceptors-in-struts2-thread-unsafe) the interceptors are thread safe, but as we deal with Value Stack in above code, I wonder if this is ok or we should synchronize above code section.

As secondary question, is there a better way to remove an element from the Value Stack ?

Comment: What's the actual *point* of removing it from the value stack? The value stack is created per-request. It goes away by itself.

Comment: While reviewing the struts framework I find that always struts put values in value stack it self and the applications read from it. I _thought_ it is not somehow recommended  that the applications put anything else in it. This is why I removed my pushed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As mentioned in [Are Interceptors in Struts2 Thread UNsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878799/are-interceptors-in-struts2-thread-unsafe) the interceptors are thread safe

**Interceptors are *NOT* thread safe**; in JAVA, however, **the method is**.

If you **don't use `static` variables nor instance variables**, everything instantiated inside a method is thread safe, that means that multiple threads accessing that method will access it sequentially, or will access it in a new instance of the containing class.

The variables will never get mixed, **and you do not need to synchronize anything**.

In addition, the `ValueStack` is stored in the `ActionContext`, that is `ThreadLocal`, and hence definitely Thread-safe.

---

BTW... why not using the Session for this ? :)

Comment: Thanks and very long story about why we can't use session ;). Can you please let me know is it ok to simply pop from value stack. is there a way to remove the added key ?!

Comment: TL;DR ? :P BTW, yes, is ok to pop the value from the stack and, AFAIK, no, there aren't other ways (but I don't usually mess with the stack directly, RomanC is your guy here :D)